# Ionic infiniteScroll: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to display all items in a category. I have the slug or the keyword of a category, I can use that to identify the parent category, I get the parent category and use that to search for all categories having similar parent. I have two pagination related errors, the errors are related.

The url `ads_url:` https://jokerleb.com/wp-json/wp/v2/ads?per_page=100&&page=. For example `page=1`

service

```
  getAds(page): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.api_url + page)
      .flatMap((ads: any[]) => {
        if (ads.length > 0) {
          return Observable.forkJoin(
            ads.map((ad: any) => {
              return this.http.get(this.ads_thumb_url + ad.id)
                .map((res: any) => {
                  let media: any = res;
                  ad.media = media;
                  return ad;
                });
            })
          );
        }
        return Observable.of([]);
      });
  }
```

ts

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public renderer: Renderer, public zone: NgZone, public adsProvider: AdsProvider) {

    this.category = this.navParams.get('category');

    this.loadAds();
  }
  loadAds(infiniteScroll?) {
    this.adsProvider.getAds(this.page).subscribe((data: any) => {
      if (!this.category.main) {
        if (this.category.slug) {
          for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i] !== undefined) {
              if (data[i].pure_taxonomies.ad_cat[0].slug.trim().toLowerCase() === this.category.slug.trim().toLowerCase()) {
                this.item_category = data[i].pure_taxonomies.ad_cat[0].term_id;
                break;
              }

            }
          }
          if (this.item_category !== undefined) {
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              if (data[i].pure_taxonomies !== undefined) {
                if (data[i].pure_taxonomies.ad_cat[0].term_id === this.item_category ||
                  data[i].pure_taxonomies.ad_cat[0].slug.trim().toLowerCase() === this.category.slug.trim().toLowerCase()) {
                  this.items.push(data[i]);
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (this.category.main === 2) {
          for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i] !== undefined) {
              if (data[i].pure_taxonomies.ad_cat[0].slug.trim().toLowerCase() === this.category.slug.trim().toLowerCase()) {
                this.item_category = data[i].pure_taxonomies.ad_cat[0].parent;
                break;
              }

            }
          }
          if (this.item_category !== undefined) {
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              if (data[i].pure_taxonomies !== undefined) {
                if (data[i].pure_taxonomies.ad_cat[0].parent === this.item_category) {
                  this.items.push(data[i]);
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if (infiniteScroll) {
        infiniteScroll.complete();
      }
    });
  }
  loadMore(infiniteScroll) {
    this.page++;
    this.loadAds(infiniteScroll);
  }
```

html

```
<ion-content fullscreen class="home-content" [ngSwitch]="tab">
  <div *ngIf="items.length>0; then thenTemplateName else elseTemplateName">
  </div>
  <ng-template #thenTemplateName>
    <div class="all-lists">
      <div class="all-category" *ngSwitchCase="1">
        <ion-card class="category-card" *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="onShowItemDetail(item);">
          <span *ngIf="item.media.length">
            <img src="{{item.media[item.media.length-1].media_details.sizes.medium.source_url}}" />
          </span>
          <div class="card-title" text-uppercase>
            <h4 color="secondary">{{item?.title.rendered}}</h4>
          </div>
        </ion-card>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="loadMore($event)" loadingSpinner="bubbles">
      <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template #elseTemplateName>
    <div class="all-lists">
      <div class="all-category" *ngSwitchCase="1">
        <ion-card text-center>
          <ion-card-header>
            This Category is empty
          </ion-card-header>
          <ion-card-content>
            This Category is empty
          </ion-card-content>
        </ion-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ion-content>
```

Sometimes I get `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`, if item not found, I don't get the error, the error happens if I scroll down too much, `loadMore()` function gets called, it finds nothing and I get the error.

I might have two problems in my code, due to `loadMore` and pagination, the first one being the error above and the second one is that sometimes the last 2 or 3 items don't show. Perhaps I'm increasing the page without checking if there are still items on to be displayed. I don't know how to fix that.

I think if there's a way to tell whether items exist before paginating, both errors will be fixed.

Comment: Did my answer help you? If you compare my `loadAds()` code with yours, I actually made just small adjustments. Let me know.

Comment: @SallyCJ your answer is good but it's not loading as many ads as my code, and I'm trying to figure out why, maybe it's your code, maybe it's the server, maybe it's my code, maybe i made a logic mistake, trying to understand what's happening

Comment: Can you create a demo on StackBlitz with all the code you used? Or somewhere else where we could actually test your app?

Comment: @SallyCJ I tried importing the project to stackblitz but it says that they only import automatically angular projects, here's the project if you could test it locally, you'd see that some items arent showing like ford, only one ford shows up https://github.com/elieobeid7/jokerleb/tree/social-login-untested

Comment: @SallyCJ please clone `social-login-untested` branch, deploy it, go to ford, for example you'll see that only 1 car shows, the brach that is deployed now is master branch

Comment: Please ignore my previous comment. I've updated my answer, and although it may not exactly solve the problems stated in the question, I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(I'm changing my answer to letting you know the problem with the "missing items".)*

*From your comment:*

> please clone `social-login-untested` branch, deploy it, go to ford,
>   for example you'll see that only 1 car shows

*And your question:*

> I might have *two* problems in my code, due to `loadMore` and
>   pagination, the first one being the error above and the second one is
>   that sometimes the last 2 or 3 items don't show.

So I cloned the `social-login-untested` branch of your [GitHub repo](https://github.com/elieobeid7/jokerleb/tree/social-login-untested), and tested the app locally.

I went to Vehicles → Cars → Ford, and noticed that there's only one item showing, which is actually as expected since *on the first page (items 1st to 100th), there's only one "Ford" item*, and the rest are on pages #2, etc.

Which means, the rest of the "Ford" items are only visible when you *scroll down* on the page — and only *if* you can scroll down the page.. i.e. the `document`'s height is greater than the `window`'s height.

Otherwise, you're stuck on page #1's results, and pages #2 and other pages would never be loaded. On Chrome, [toggle](https://ibb.co/dyq8vU) the device toolbar → choose "Responsive" and try `400 x 320` px, like below:

[image]

At `400 x 320` px, you can scroll down, so all the "Ford" items would be loaded.

One way I could think of how you could fix the issue, is with a logic that looks something like this (see the `CategoryDetailsPage.loadAds()` in `src/pages/category-details/category-details.ts`):

```
if ( {DOCUMENT'S HEIGHT} <= {WINDOW'S HEIGHT} ) {
  // Loads next page without waiting for the scrolling to occur; but stops
  // loading when scrolling starts - for that, the logic is not included.
  this.loadMore( infiniteScroll );
} else if ( infiniteScroll ) {
  infiniteScroll.complete();
}
```

.. but (since I'm actually less experienced in AngularJS and Ionic) you would need to create that on your own.. You may also want to add a listener to the `window`/`document` `onscroll` event and stop the `loadMore()` on page scroll. And make sure there are no (or just remove/hide) duplicate items.

Nonetheless, I hope this "new" answer will help you. =)

### Additional Note

As I pointed in my *comment* to your question, if necessary, you can retrieve the total available number of pages via the header `X-WP-TotalPages`. See https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/

Comment: it didn't work the js `DOCUMENT'S HEIGHT} <= {WINDOW'S HEIGHT` I'll have to try the x-wp-totalpages

Answer (score 4):

As you already mentioned in the question, this happens when you try to access elements when they are empty. You can handle with a if check wherever you are trying to access items as follows,

```
if(data && data.length > 0){
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
}
```

Comment: you need to do the same for all arrays

Comment: Pretty sure I have tried that but will try again when I get on my computer and I will let you know

Comment: was it the issue? did you sort it out?

Answer (score 3):

Try this (I added more checks)

```
loadAds(infiniteScroll?) {
    this.adsProvider.getAds(this.page).subscribe((data: any) => {
      if (!this.category.main) {
        if (this.category.slug) {
          for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i] !== undefined && (data[i].pure_taxonomies.ad_cat || []).length ) {
              if (data[i].pure_taxonomies.ad_cat[0].slug.trim().toLowerCase() === this.category.slug.trim().toLowerCase()) {
                this.item_category = data[i].pure_taxonomies.ad_cat[0].term_id;

                break;
              }

            }
          }
          if (this.item_category !== undefined) {
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              if (data[i].pure_taxonomies !== undefined && (data[i].pure_taxonomies.ad_cat || []).length) {
                if (data[i].pure_taxonomies.ad_cat[0].term_id === this.item_category ||
                  data[i].pure_taxonomies.ad_cat[0].slug.trim().toLowerCase() === this.category.slug.trim().toLowerCase()) {

                  this.items.push(data[i]);
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (this.category.main === 2) {
          for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i] !== undefined && data[i].pure_taxonomies && (data[i].pure_taxonomies.ad_cat || []).length) {
              if (data[i].pure_taxonomies.ad_cat[0].slug.trim().toLowerCase() === this.category.slug.trim().toLowerCase()) {
                this.item_category = data[i].pure_taxonomies.ad_cat[0].parent;

                break;
              }

            }
          }
          if (this.item_category !== undefined) {
            for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
              if (data[i].pure_taxonomies !== undefined && (data[i].pure_taxonomies.ad_cat || []).length) {
                if (data[i].pure_taxonomies.ad_cat[0].parent === this.item_category) {

                  this.items.push(data[i]);
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
      if (infiniteScroll) {
        infiniteScroll.complete();
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: the error is fixed i think but what i can't understand is that, if you give it a quick test, you'll see that some categories like bmw work great, maybe 1 item missing but ford has so many items missing. Although both have the correct slug and parent category https://github.com/elieobeid7/jokerleb/tree/social-login-untested

Comment: @Lynob It's a bit hard to know what your problem is exactly. Your question was about undefined index, which is solved now. Maybe edit the question to clearly state what does not work. I tried your projet and it seems to work for me, but I don't know what should be displayed exactly...